# Cookiecutter-django custom User field is never saved to DB

Tags: python, django, django-models, cookiecutter-django

I'm struggling with a banal (I guess) issue with `cookiecutter-django`...

I added the field `invitation_code` to `users.models.User`:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Default custom user model for pintable.
    If adding fields that need to be filled at user signup,
    check forms.SignupForm and forms.SocialSignupForms accordingly.
    """

    #: First and last name do not cover name patterns around the globe
    name = CharField(_("Full name"), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = None  # type: ignore
    last_name = None  # type: ignore

    invitation_code = CharField(
        _("Invitation code"), max_length=8, null=True, blank=True
    )
```

Then I added the same field to `users.forms.UserSignupForm`:

```py
class UserSignupForm(SignupForm):
    """
    Form that will be rendered on a user sign up section/screen.
    Default fields will be added automatically.
    Check UserSocialSignupForm for accounts created from social.
    """

    invitation_code = CharField(
        label=_("Invitation code"),
        widget=TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": _("Invitation code")}),
    )
```

The problem is that when a new user is saved to DB, the `invitation_code` field is always `None`. What am I missing..?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

To make things work I had to customize `users.adapters.AccountAdapter` as well:

```py
def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=True):
        dummy_user = super().save_user(request, user, form, commit=False)
        dummy_user.invitation_code = form.cleaned_data["invitation_code"]
        if commit:
            dummy_user.save()
```